# Window.open within php while loop not functioning correctly

Tags: php, javascript, window.open

I have a while loop that creates multiple tables with information inside.
Within each table is a facebook and twitter icon.
A reader can share the info or tweet the info that's within the table via an onclick event.

Here's each event.

```
<?php
echo'<script type="text/javascript">
function tweet(){

var sharer = "https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?source=webclient&text=',$title2,' - http://www.globatum.com/lite/post.php?id=',$row['id'],'";
window.open(sharer,\'sharer\' , \'width=600,height=500\');}
</script>';
?>
<?php
echo'<script type="text/javascript">
function fbshare(){

var share = "https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=http://www.globatum.com/lite/post.php?id=',$row['id'],'";
window.open(share,\'share\' , \'width=600,height=500\');}
</script>';
?>
```

The odd thing is that it works. somewhat. When I click the fb icon a small window with the dialogue will pop up. Same for twitter.
The problem is that when I look at the header of the popup... it's using the same info from all of the tables.

What I want...

Table 1 fb icon clicks should open window
https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=http://www.makeupsite.com/post.php?id=1

table 2 will be
https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=http://www.makeupsite.com/post.php?id=2

table 3 ..
https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=http://www.makeupsite.com/post.php?id=3
etc etc

however when I click on the icons...

table 1: opens window
https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=http://www.makeupsite.com/post.php?id=1 (GOOD)

table 2: opens window...
https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=http://www.makeupsite.com/post.php?id=1 (BAD)

table 3: opens window...
https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=http://www.makeupsite.com/post.php?id=1 (BAD)

It sounds like a simple sql issue but when I pull up the page source I get

Table 1

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function tweet(){

var sharer = "https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?source=webclient&text=random title - http://www.makeupsite.com/post.php?id=39";
window.open(sharer,'sharer' , 'width=600,height=500');}
</script><script type="text/javascript">
function fbshare(){

var share = "https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=http://www.makeupsite.com/post.php?id=39";
window.open(share,'share' , 'width=600,height=500');}
</script>
```

Table 2

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function tweet(){

var sharer = "https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?source=webclient&text=random title - http://www.makeupsite.com/post.php?id=43";
window.open(sharer,'sharer' , 'width=600,height=500');}
</script><script type="text/javascript">
function fbshare(){

var share = "https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=http://www.makeupsite.com/post.php?id=43";
window.open(share,'share' , 'width=600,height=500');}
</script>
```

Basically the page source is saying one thing...but the window.open is doing something completely different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're redefining the same function over and over and over again. Depending on the browser, you'll always call either the first or last instance of tweet() or fbshare() you define.

In the footer of your doc, set up a single function:

```
function shareLink(targetURL){
    window.open(targetURL, 'share', 'width=600,height=500');
}
```

Then, tie that to your social buttons:

```
onclick=shareLink("[twitter URL here]");
```

or

```
onclick=shareLink("[facebook URL here]");
```

See what I'm getting at?

**EDIT** whoops, helps if I get the names right

Comment: I understand and it makes a lot of sense. How would I pass the variable through the onclick event? following your method does not open up a new window. Should I try something like onClick="socialWindow( shareLink(stuff in here) )"?

Comment: [`code`]<a href="#" onclick=shareLink("http://www.google.com")><img src="/images/twitter.png" width="30px"></a>[`code`]
tried this and got nothing